# No Flutter view avilable on device if Row has two Text widgets

Tags: flutter

I am facing issue while rendering a Row. I want to show two separate Text in a Row.
but view not visible on the device.

```
 Row(   mainAxisAlignment: 
             MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("dataewrwer"),
                   Text("dataewrwer")],
                   )
```

if i wrap  both Text with the Expanded then it works.

```
Row(   mainAxisAlignment: 
             MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, 
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child:  RaisedButton(onPressed: (){},child: Text("button"),),),
                   Expanded(child:
                   Text("dataewrwer"),)],
                   )
```

what is the main Issue with the Row Widget even if i put RaisedButton and Text it does not render on device and shows error

> Error connecting to the service protocol: Exception: No Flutter view is available
>   Exited (sigterm)

Comment: what is the parent of that Row?

Comment: @diegoveloper Padding then Column at the top

Comment: Add more code please

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on your code

```
     <Widget>[
            Text("dataewrwer"),
               Text("dataewrwer"),)],
```

There is an extra ")"  , remove that and it should work

```
   <Widget>[
            Text("dataewrwer"),
            Text("dataewrwer"),
           ],
```

This works fine for me:

```
  Center(
        child: new Container(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("text1"),
                Text("text2"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )),
      )
```

Comment: sorry for copy-pasting and missing the ')'. but in actual code, there is no syntax error. the issue is with the hierarchy of widgets. sometimes Row works and sometimes it does not. is there any limitation regarding using Row widgets?